# tag for UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbaritem

When I use the this method to initialize a `UITabBarItem`:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image tag:(NSInteger)tag
```

Do I need to have a distinct tag for each tab bar item, or (since I don't use them) can I simply use the same tag value for all of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just leave them all as 0 or any other number you choose.  Every UIView can potentially have a different tag, and Interface Builder sets them all to 0 by default.  I haven't run into any problems with this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll trust you on that. ; )

Comment: My iPhone app had all of them 0 for a long time and it was fine. Now i'm going to set them to values just so I can do 'if' or 'switch' statements to easily identify which element is sending events etc.

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's [UITabBarItem](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference:

> *tag* - The receiver’s tag, an integer that you can use to identify bar item objects in your application.

So it looks like it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I saw that, but it seemed unclear whether they use it for anything.

Comment: Just by us to "identify objects"